# How do I export data using PostgreSQL COPY command in required format?

Tags: postgresql

I have some sample data in my PostgreSQL 9.5 db like follows:

```
ID(integer)   value_1(numeric)   value_2(numeric)  array(text)
1             25.2               14.1              1,112,292,19.7
2             11.3               5.9               2,30,110,22.3,60,270,30.1
```

I am exporting this data in `my_table` using Postgres `COPY` command to a custom text file like this:

```
Copy
(
Select
ID, value_1,
value_2, array
from
my_table
Order by ID
) to '~my_path/output.str' With DELIMITER ',';
```

I get the exported output like:

```
1,25.2,14.1,1\,112\,292\,19.7\
2,11.3,5.9,2\,30\,110\,22.3\,60\,270\,30.1\
```

However, my desired output is:

```
1,25.2,14.1,1,112,292,19.7
2,11.3,5.9,2,30,110,22.3,60,270,30.1
```

How do I remove these unwanted characters `\` in `COPY` command export output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot.  Just ask an editor to replace `\,` with `,`.

Otherwise, if the desired output format is really what you want, you can change the query:

```
SELECT id::text || ',' || 
       value_1::text || ',' || ... || 
       your_array_column
...
```

In any case, I'd suggest fixing your array data type.  Storing numbers as text looks really bad.

Comment: I am puzzled by this error "ERROR:  function array_to_string(text, unknown) does not exist. You might need to add explicit type casts". I get this error due to last line which is array_to_string(array_column,','). I am calling this array from a table where values are stored as text. Do I have to first convert them to array by unnest??

Comment: I was confused by the column name, thinking it was a `text[]` as opposed to `text`.  Really, fix your column/data types ;)

Comment: hehe I will :) but for now problem is resolved. Thanks!